# Are there kiosks at Malpensa Airport?

Tags: tickets, check-in, easyjet, mxp

Is there a kiosk at Malpensa where I can print my easyJet boarding pass?

Comment: Will be EasyJet!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In April 2017, easyjet did **not** have check-in kiosks, however if you've already checked in online, the bag drop desk will print your boarding pass for free.